# show invalid DateTimes

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I made an application that shows me the full content of a table in an OracleDatabase where i only have restricted access to.

The Application simply takes the User-Entered Server IP, login-details and command from textfields and sends the command to the Oracle server. The Application is used to just show the Content of Tables i have access to.

I have the same Database 2 times with different values. While its working for the first database, the second one is giving me the following Error-Message

```
year month and day parameters describe an un-representable datetime
```

(I am getting the german version of the Error-Msg, but this should be it)
This Error is Caused due to invalid dates in the Values (example 99.99.2014, dates that do not exist)

I am not allowed to change values in the Oracle Database, but i need to view the values to print the birthdate on a paper later in another application.

My theory solution is the following: Make the Date that i get from the server be shown as a string, not as date - My Problem: I dont know how

My Program (VB) is doing the following:
Get User entrys -> send select command to server -> put results into datatable -> use datatable as datasource for Datagridview

**EDIT**

```
Public Sub New(ByRef OracleConnection As Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Command As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    Try
        Dim oraCommand As New Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(Command, OracleConnection)
        Dim OraDA As New Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter(oraCommand)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        OraDA.Fill(dt)
        dgv.DataSource = dt
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
        dgv.Columns(dgv.ColumnCount - 1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        OracleConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

by removing the try/catch i found out the error comes in the following line

```
 oraDA.Fill(dt)
```

the command is typically something like `select * from database.table` where the Date column is called `GEBDATUM`

Comment: Where in the code are you getting that error?  When reading the data? Processing it?  Reproduction steps are essential, we don't have access to your computer!

Comment: If the value is stored in the database then it cannot be a datetime. So perhaps the best approach is to read it back as is (a string probably) and then try to convert to a date. But you should add the code that tries to read  those values if you want an answer

Comment: What is the data type of the field in Oracle. If it is a date type, is has to hold a valid date. If it is a string, then there is nothing to convert.

Comment: The Type is probably `Date`, i added code-snippet into the post

Comment: I don't understand how is possible that a column of type `Date` could accept a value as `99.99.2014`

Comment: The type is probably date?  Why don't you run a describe command and verify that?

Comment: @Steve It was just an example! I actually dont know the values inside the column. 99.99.2014 was just an example of an invalid Date. Just like the 31th Feb 2001 would be.

Comment: @DanBracuk Because i didnt know about such a command - im new to sql and vb. ill try to figure out how it works.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the errorneous date time format to be processed? Or you want to know why there is such error?

Comment: i need to work with the data so i have to be able to put it into my datatable. If you are able to make that possible, great. If you can also tell me how you made it possible - perfect. But in the end i just need the data in my datatable to work with it

Comment: Is it possible that you are querying a view or synonym where the underlying data structure has changed?

Comment: I found out that my company kinda fooled me unintentionally. The Problem is, that there are different versions of theDatabase, one is using Date format YYYY.MM.DD and the other one is using DD.MM.YYYY .. and for some reason vb cant handle this. I still didnt find out how to fix that.